# return Point(int(firstArg), int(secondArg)) # firstArg and secondArg are just x and y number values

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to have pyautogui move the mouse whenever it detects a color but for some reason whenever I try running it keeps on prompting this error, I have run this code before and it worked perfectly fine. pls help

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJACL.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErHH0.png)

Comment: Please include your code and error in the question as text (use the `{}` code formatting button) instead of as screenshots. (Can’t copy and paste from a screenshot, among other things.)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because "locateAllOnScreen" returns a "generator" which can be looped through which contains all instances of the image. You may be looking for "locateOnScreen".

Here are some example on how to use the two different functions:

```
# Will loop through all instances of 'img.png'
for pos in pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('img.png')
    # Code here...

# Will find one instance and return the position
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img.png')
```

[This](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) link has some good information on the different methods